# js DOM lookup vs globals

Tags: javascript, dom, global-variables

This has no practical effect for me (not trying to optimize my head off) but I'm asking for a better understanding of the relationships in the browser environment.  I have many small objects, the user picks items from three `select` elements and each object does a calculation based on its own values for the selected variables.  Since the method gets called many times is it more noble to say:

```
function calculate() {  
  var a = document.forms.params.ONESEL.value;
  var b = document.forms.params.TWOSEL.value;
  var c = document.forms.params.THRSEL.value;
... // do things }
```

or

```
bucket.a = document.forms.params.ONESEL.value;
bucket.b = document.forms.params.TWOSEL.value;
bucket.c = document.forms.params.THRSEL.value;
function calculate() {  
  var a = bucket.a;
  var b = bucket.b;
  var c = bucket.c;
... // do things }
```

Or is there no real difference at all, with the DOM lookup being effectively the same as the global reference?  And would the first version be substantially worse if it used `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: Between the 2 I don't think there is any difference in performance, as you are just accessing variables. If you had to do the DOM look up though, you will be looping through the DOM elements to find the ID you specify every time (At least as far as I know) so that will have some performance effect.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Thanks Nicholas.  I'm not surprised; I just have this reluctance to hit the DOM too much because it seems like a different, more expensive domain.  But I expect that's just a superstition, and all the animals are equal.